# how to find film title that have 2 actors in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Lets say this is my tables :

```
************
* film     * 
************    
* title    *
* film_id  *
************

************    
* actors   *
************
* film_id  *
* actor_id *
************
```

I would like to find the title of the film in which two actors participate `actor_id = 22 and actor_id = 23` 
how to write the query ?

I tried :

```
SELECT title 
FROM film 
WHERE film_id IN(
    SELECT film_id, COUNT(*) 
    FROM actors 
    WHERE actor_id=22 OR actor_id=23
    GROUP BY film_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following query should make it for you.

```
SELECT title 
FROM film f, actors a1, actors a2 
WHERE f.film_id=a1.film_id AND a1.actor_id=22 
      AND f.film_id=a2.film_id AND a2.actor_id=23;
```

Joins are also a better way to handle it:

```
SELECT title 
FROM film f 
JOIN actors a1 ON f.film_id = a1.film_id
JOIN actors a2 ON f.film_id = a2.film_id
WHERE  a1.actor_id = 22 
       AND a2.actor_id = 23;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inner join to the actor table twice and set the individual `actor_id` as criteria in each join it will require both actors to be in the film. as a result you'll only return films that have both actors.

```
SELECT film.title 
FROM film 
INNER JOIN actors actors1
    ON film.film_id = actors1.film_id
    AND actors1.actor_id=22
INNER JOIN actors actors2 
    ON film.film_id = actors2.film_id
    AND actors2.actor_id=23
GROUP BY film.title
```